# Column/Validation guarantees with Deedle

Tags: f#, deedle

Is there a way to express the notion that a data frame has already been validated? The best way I can think of is creating a wrapper type to restrict access. I welcome any suggestions.

Simple example:

```ml
#r "nuget: Deedle"

open Deedle

type CustomFrame = 
    | Some of Frame<int,string>
    | None
let map mapping option = match option with None -> None | Some x -> Some (mapping x)
let iter action option = match option with None -> () | Some x -> action x

let parse (df:Frame<_,_>) = 
    let keys = df.ColumnKeys |> Set.ofSeq
    if keys.Contains("Entry") && keys.Contains("Color") then
        df    
        |> Frame.indexRowsInt "Entry"
        |> CustomFrame.Some
    else
    CustomFrame.None

let go (df:CustomFrame) =
    df
    |> map (Frame.filterRowsBy "Color" "Red")

let data = "Entry;Color;N\n1;Red;7\n2;Blue;42\n3;Blue;21"
let bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes data
let stream =  new MemoryStream( bytes )

Frame.ReadCsv(stream = stream,separators = ";",hasHeaders = true)
|> parse
|> go
|> iter (fun d-> d.Print())
```

```
     Color N 
1 -> Red   7
```

Comment: Why the custom clone of `option`?

Comment: The example was simplified. Often, I have a list of functions, where I operate on columns which I have created before in another function like `aggregate |> pivot |> calculateMin1 |> calculateMin2 |> select`. If I use Option for all of them I wouldn't see the error if I get the order wrong.

Comment: Use `Result` then?

Comment: Suppose I create a column `min1` in `calculateMin1` and use it in `calculateMin2`. If all of my functions return `Ok frame` and I do `aggregate |> pivot |> calculateMin2 |> calculateMin1  |> select`. It compiles and I have a problem in my production code. Would you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two suggestions:

- Have `parse` return a standard `Option` value, as Fyodor suggests.
- Short-circuit the computation if validation fails. In other words, if `parse` returns `None`, don't call `go` and `iter` at all.

If you really want to program defensively after `parse`, and no further validation is required, you no longer need a `None` value. So you could use a simplified wrapper type to ensure you always have a validated frame:

```ml
type ValidFrame = Valid of Frame<int,string>

let map f (Valid df) = f df |> Valid
let iter (f : _ -> unit) (Valid df) = f df
let go = map (Frame.filterRowsBy "Color" "Red")
```

And then use it like this:

```ml
Frame.ReadCsv(stream = stream,separators = ";",hasHeaders = true)
|> parse
|> Option.map (
    Valid
      >> go
      >> iter (fun df -> df.Print()))
```

However, personally, I consider the wrapper type to be overkill unless there's a compelling reason for it.

Comment: Short-circuiting sounds interesting. Thank you! I really like the fact that Deedle provides some sort of easy to use row index safety and I was just wondering if I can have the same for columns names. Wrapper types seems a bit overkill, I agree.